# Partitioning the domain of $f$ so that it has a finite greatest value in every partition?

Tags: calculus, functions

Is it possible to partition the domain of every unbounded $f$ so that is has a finite greatest value in every such partition?

How many partitions are needed? A finite number, countable number, uncountable number of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A finite number of subsets of the domain will never suffice: If $f$ is bounded on $A_i$, $i=1,\ldots, n$, then $f$ is bounded on $\bigcup_i A_i$ by the biggest of the numbers $\sup_{A_i} f$.

But a countable number will always do: As $f\colon D \to \mathbf R$ is unbounded, there is a sequence $(x_n)$ in $D$ such that $f(x_n)$ is increasing and $f(x_n) \to \infty$. (We can construct such a sequence inductively: Start with any $x_1 \in D$, and as $\max\{n, f(x_n)\}$ is not a bound for $f$, choose $x_{n+1}\in D$ with $f(x_{n+1}) > \max\{n, f(x_n)\}$). Now define 
$$ D_1 := \{x \in D: f(x) \le f(x_1) \}, 
\qquad D_n := \{x \in D: f(x_{n-1}) < f(x) \le f(x_n)\}, \, n\ge 1 $$
Then $D = \bigcup_n D_n$ and $f|_{D_n}$ has the greatest value $f(x_n)$.

[corrected typo]

Comment: Why do you take the maximum of two numbers: $n$ and $f(x_n)$? I mean, if I replaced $\max\{n, f(x_n)\}$ with $f(x_n)$, would it change anything? No real number is a bound for $f$ anyway.

Comment: Then you have the risk that $f(x_n)$ may not be unbounded.

Comment: You start with $x_1$. Then you choose a $x_2$ such that $f(x_2) < f(x_1)$. And continue the process as $n$ tends to infinity. What's the point of max function here? $f(x_n)$ will never be bounded because $f$ isn't - we're always choosing $x_n$ such that $f(x_n)$ is greater than $f(x_{n-1})$.

Comment: No. We have to ensure that $f(x_n) > n$ (or some other unbounded sequence), otherwise it may happen, that say $f(x_n) = 1 - \frac 1n$.

Comment: Oh, I got it. Thanks.

Comment: I think we forgot that $f$ has to be continuous: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem and example 3 here: http://oregonstate.edu/instruct/mth251/cq/Stage4/Lesson/EVT.html